# Circular import when using flask-mail in flask-restful project

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-mail

I'm working on a Flask project which include sending confirmation email links. However, by using `flask-restful`, there is a problem of circular importing modules.
In my `app.py` file, I've imported modules and use `api.add_resource`

```
# app.py file
from flask_restful import Api
from flask import Flask
from account import Register
from flask_mail import Mail

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ''
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config.from_pyfile('core/config.py')

mail = Mail(app)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Register, '/register')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And in my `account.py` file, I need to send an email for each POST request like this

```
from app import mail
class Register(Resource):
    # init some msg and configuration
    mail.send(msg)
```

Now this is a circular import, since `app.py` import `account.py` and `account.py` import `app.py` to use `mail`. Can anyone have any solution for this problem without abandon using `flask-restful` module?

Answer (score 0):

Most simple and direct answer will be: import module, not symbol from module.

So, instead of `from account import Register` do `import account` and then `api.add_resource(account.Register, '/register')`.

Similar approach for `account.py` should work as well:

```
import app


class Register(Resource):
    app.mail.send(msg)
```

Some basic explanations can be found at https://github.com/Khan/style-guides/blob/master/style/python.md#imports

Comment: I solved this problem by add them to the `__init.py__` and import to `main.py` file to initialize. Anyway, thanks for your help